# Typescript converting a JSON object to Typescript class

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Hello I am attempting to change an array of JSON objects to a TypeScript class. However the method seems to crash every I attempt to assign a Json object attribute to a typescript attribute.

Typescript interface

```
export interface marker {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
}
```

Typescript method

```
public markers: marker[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.mapService.GetPhotosById(this.id).subscribe(resultlisting => {
        this.values = resultlisting;
        console.log(this.values); //SHOW IN PICTURE
        this.ChangetoMarkers(this.values);
    }, error => this.errorMessage = error);
}

ChangetoMarkers(someArray: Observable<any[]>) {

    for (let entry of someArray) {
        let mark: marker;
        mark.lat = Number(entry.latitude); //Attempt to convert to number
        mark.lng = +entry.longitude; //2nd attempt to convert to number
        this.markers.push(mark);
    };
    console.log(this.markers); //DOES NOT REACH THIS
}
```

Map Service

```
GetPhotosById(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
        .post(this.config.apiEndpoint + "mapPhotos/" + id)
        .map(this.extractJson).catch(this.handleErrors);

};
private extractJson(res: Response) {
    let data = res.json();
    return data;
}
private handleErrors(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.log(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

I have researched the issue and have attempted to apply the interger cast but it does not seem to work. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Those are not "JSON objects" but javascript objects. Any exceptions thrown?

Comment: you're trying to assign properties to a variable that has no value, write `let mark: marker = {}` instead

Comment: No exceptions thrown surprisingly

Comment: Ok great I'll try that in a moment

Comment: Name types with initial caps please. It is hard to read otherwise and this convention is very widely accepted.

Comment: Got it. I appreciate the advice. Very new to typescript

Comment: based on your updated question, it does not seem that this method takes an `Observable` at all. It seems to take an `Array`. Please verify this. Just log values before you pass it to `changeToMarkers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As  Mauricio Poppe noted in his comment, you are trying to access the properties of a variable that has no value.

```
changeToMarkers(points: Array<{latitude: number, longitude: number}>) {
  this.markers = entries.map(({latitude: lat, longitude: lng}) => ({
    lat,
    lng
  }));

  console.log(this.markers);
}
```

No number conversions are necessary because the deserialized representations of latitude and longitude are already compatible numeric values.

Comment: It does not reach the console.log(this.markers) statement.

Comment: @RyeGuy what happens? Does it reach the subscribe? Note I changed the names slightly for convention, be sure to update your template (or change the names back ;))

Comment: I really appreciate the help. However it does not seem to reach the subscribe. I change the parameter back the Observable<any>

Comment: @RyeGuy the type doesn't change the runtime behavior at all. Can you add the code that calls the `changetoMarkers` to your question? More context is required.

Comment: Added to my post above. It occurs in the OnInit

Comment: @RyeGuy see updated answer. If that doesn't work your response has a different shape than you think.

Comment: I have shown a picture of the object being logged in console. I have manipulated your solution to no avail. One more attempt (since your a Typescript pro) would be tremendous

Comment: I wouldn't call myself a pro but from looking at the values object in the screenshot I don't see why my solution would not work. Remember that the method now takes an array not an observable

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ChangetoMarkers(someArray: any[]) {
    console.log("array",someArray);
    for (let entry of someArray) {
        let mark: marker = {lat: entry.latitude, lng: entry.longitude};
        console.log("mark", mark);
        this.markers.push(mark);
    };
    console.log("markers",this.markers); 
}
```

It isn't as elegant as Aluan Haddad's, but it should allow you to determine at which point it is breaking if for some reason this still doesn't work, by logging someArray before the loop, the marks before being pushed, and this.markers after to determine exactly where the problem is breaking down.